# Using data from database in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, mysql, forms, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to make a POS application in MS VS 2015. I have created the database in MS SQL Management studio and am now trying to call it in VS 2015. More specifically trying to show the data in a combo box in windows form app. I did the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private Coffee_shopEntities cse = new Coffee_shopEntities();

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       comboBox1.DataSource = cse.tblProductTypes;
       comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
       comboBox1.ValueMember = "ProductType";
   }
}
```

But nothing shows up in the `combo box`, it's still empty.
 And yes the table has values stored in it.

Comment: No, its still the same

Comment: are you using a DataTable anywhere in your code..? how are you binding the data and or opening the Table ...? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w67sdsex(v=vs.100).aspx have you stopped to think about doing a simple google search..?  load the data in the Form_Load event

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, if there is a question you wanted to ask could you please be more explicit and precise about what it is your asking and where you are having a problem?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you doing this in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event?  If the control never has items in the first place, how is the selected index going to change?

Populate the control when the form loads:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load); // or use the form designer
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = cse.tblProductTypes;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ProductType";
}
```

The `SelectedIndexChanged` is invoked by the control itself when a user changes the selected item.  It's not where you would initially populate the control with items.  (Though you *can* use it to *re-populate* the control with *different* items when one is selected.  That would be a pretty jarring UX however.)

Comment: Yes, youve pointed that out correctly. However, its still not working. Can you please guide me on some tutorial of some form, where i can learn on how i can connect a database and use it in a form application? I would be extremely thankful, its been almost four days since i've been trying to do this but no luck.

Comment: @MuneebRehman: There are *many* tutorials and examples available.  Google is good for finding such things.  Stack Overflow doesn't really serve as a personal tutor.  If you can clarify what you mean by "not working" then perhaps this community can help.  But you're going to have to debug your own code and provide us with information about the problem.  We can't do that for you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZP8Nqw2_qU

This is the tutorial i was following. However, Visual Studio 2015 didnt have the option of database diagrams, so i downloaded the MS SQL management studio, made the database there. But had no clue how to link that with VS 2015. When i finally managed to do that, i wasnt able to call the 'Coffee_shopEntities()'. I then stumbled upon the entity framework and then made the entity ADO.NET Entity Model after which i was able to call the 'Coffee_shopEntities()'. Once i called that, here i am.

Comment: I am really sorry i am new to all this. And havent been able to find any thing useful. There are many tutorials, but not what i am looking for. This tutorial has exactly what i am looking for, but I just keep stumbling over problem after problem after probelm. I just want to be able to access a database and be able to query it through windows form app.

Comment: @MuneebRehman: I doubt anybody here is going to watch videos for you.  Honestly, this community would like to help.  But you're going to need to specify the problem more.  You might try different tutorials as well, to give you more exposure to the underlying concepts.  You're also going to want to familiarize yourself with debugging.  If all you do is copy/paste code that you find online and hope that it works then you're really not going to get very far.